# how to Add SIP contacts list and their online status in CSipSImple ?

Tags: android, csip-simple

I am learning to add one SIP contacts list on Csipsimple. and I am looking for how to get online status of contacts throug pjsip.

In org.pjsip.pjsua.pjsipJNI.java, I read these lines. Could I use them to get someone's online status from SIP server?

```
public final static native int pjsua_acc_info_online_status_get(long jarg1, pjsua_acc_info jarg1_);
  public final static native long pjsua_acc_info_online_status_text_get(long jarg1, pjsua_acc_info jarg1_);
```

Of course, I also read these lines in org.pjsip.pjsua.pjsua_acc_info. but I did not know how should I use because It seems not for read one contact's status.

```
    public int getOnline_status() {
        return pjsuaJNI.pjsua_acc_info_online_status_get(swigCPtr, this);
      }

  public void setOnline_status_text(pj_str_t value) {
    pjsuaJNI.pjsua_acc_info_online_status_text_set(swigCPtr, this, pj_str_t.getCPtr(value), value);
  }
```

could you help me! Any advice is of great help .

Comment: Do you found solution to that?

Comment: Yes . I have written a web service which is running in asterisk-server . I have call this web service from android app . The web servic returns me who is online . By this process I have solved this problem .